# Kafka consumer - how to add a topic

Tags: addition, consumer, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka

In a scenario, where I have N consumers (all consumers have 1 stream/no partitioning), each subscribed to separate set of topics, how to process new topics, added by producers?

Should I create new consumer to each added topic?
Or can I add this topic to already working consumer? (how to do that?)

Or better keep 1 consumer group with N consumers and not divide topics between N consumers(streams)?

Comment: added, but unfortunately list of relevant tags is quite short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial config, as described, where topics devided between consumers of the same consumer group is not goood at all.
Consumer will not be able to fail=over each other, because they have different lists of topics. Kafka will issue unnecessary rebalance.

You need not add consumer for each added topic - you better consume all such topics from beginning, adding them to common path like /MYTOPICS/*

You better divide topics by partitions and add new partitions if you need.
This will be transparent and without effort.